# How to get a value in a range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, named-ranges

| Name | ID | Formula1 | Formula2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 2 | =user_name (outputs "John") |  |
| Smith | 3 | =user_name (outputs "Smith") |  |
| Tom | 1 | =user_name (outputs "Tom") |  |

In the spreadsheet above, if I define the "Name" column as range "user_name" and put `=user_name` in another cell, it will output the value of the cell in the same row in `user_name` range. In this case, the named range seems to be treated as a value.

Now, consider I have another table

| Order_ID | Customer_ID | User_Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3003 | 1 | =filter(Name,u_id = order_uid) (want this to output "Tom" but it won't) |
| 3004 | 3 | =filter(Name,u_id = B3) (This works and output "Smith") |
| 3005 | 2 |  |

What I am trying to do is to get user name from Table1 and put it in Table2 according to the customer_ID using the filter function. I named the column "Customer_ID" as `order_uid` and "ID" column in Table1 as `u_id`. But

```
=filter(Name,u_id = order_uid)
```

won't work. It will treat `order_uid` as a range and compare it with range `u_id` and outputs an array of `Name` rows where `u_id`'s value equal to `Customer_ID`'s value. In this case the array has only one value: "Smith".

My question is, in the formula

```
=filter(Name,u_id = B3)
```

I prefer to use named range instead of A1 notation(B3). Is there a way to get the value of a named range of the same row, so I can do something like

```
=filter(Name,u_id = sane_row_value(order_uid))
```

instead of

```
=filter(Name,u_id = B1) 
=filter(Name,u_id = B2)
=filter(Name,u_id = B3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will accept your answer in the other question.

Answer (score 1):

Try in C1

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(order_uid,{user_id,user_name},2,0)))
```

[image]